# API Platform DTO not used in Swagger documentation

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have an entity and a DTO that I would like to use in POST requests. Here are my two classes.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Dto\TestPost;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "post"={
 *              "input"=TestPost::class
 *          }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={}
 * )
 */
final class Test
{
    public string $foo;

    public string $bar;
}
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Dto;

final class TestPost
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public string $xxx;
}
```

I expected that in the Swagger documentation the field "xxx" would be shown. Instead the two fields "foo" and "bar" of the original entity are shown. Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I have to define the output, too. It works when I add an "output" key like so:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Dto\TestPost;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "post"={
 *              "input"=TestPost::class,
 *              "output"=false
 *          }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={}
 * )
 */
final class Test
{
    public string $foo;

    public string $bar;
}
```